# White line on image when Windows scale is 125%

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, scaling

I have a specific problem. A website has an image with 5px solid border and when I change Windows scale settings to 125% I see an empty line between image and border.

[image]

[image]

```css
img {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x140/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net">
```

I'm testing it on Google Chrome v91. It looks like Chrome has a problem with subpixels when zooming/scaling.

I have also noticed that this white line is actually a background color of an image where white is probably default.

I have tried many settings but nothing works. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the image in a div, and setting it to 100% like this:

```css
img {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=”image”>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/290x140/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net">
</div>
```

Let me know if it works or not. If you want to set the size of the image, change the size of the div.

Comment: Actually, the image is wrapped with an "a" tag but it doesn't matter because width and height settings didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more of the code than please?

Answer (score 0):

(for anyone running in to this in the future)

A workaround for this specific problem is to style the background of the parent container the same color as the border.

```
#image {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If the border color changes on, say, on hover, then change the background color with it.